# hierarchy parent child relationship datagrid C# window application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I want to create hierarchy parent child relationship datagrid C# window application
using [collapsible-rows-in-datagrid](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/expandable-and-collapsible-rows-in-datagrid-in-C-Sharp-winforms/)

but now i want to add Add Edit Image In this Grid like

[image]

please advice for this

Comment: Use [DataGridViewImageColumn](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiW5vycoZPNAhUKVFIKHZodDDoQFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNE03rGOD7WtLZKzgf8qO_RVG15RUw&sig2=cgGr6nvOIaF9hwNtoctiEQ)

Comment: I am Using DataGrid not DataGridView

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView doesn't directly support row expanding/collapsing, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5269650/2858407).

Although following trick doesn't seem robust to me, you can use filtering by a hidden column to emulate row collapsing/expanding. To make a +/- sign you can engage [DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) with custom check images.

Once user checks/unchecks a cell in this column, you can traverse all children of the affected row and update the hidden column value to show or hide them.

By comparison with master/detail approach this trick allows to show deep hierarchies.